# A fluctuating riddle

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

> My prefix is a guardian  of the forest
> My infix is too much for French people
> My suffix is often seen by "snake charmers"
> **What am I?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Entropy

My prefix is a guardian of the forest

> [Ent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ent)

My infix is too much for French people

> "Trop" is French for "too much"

My suffix is often seen by "snake charmers"

> Py - I think "snake charmers" here refers to Python developers who have to deal with a lot of files with extension **.py** and packages ending in **py**

Title

> Entropy is a thermodynamic quantity often interpreted as the degree of disorder or randomness in a physical system.

Comment: Wow, 5 whole minutes, I'm stunned.

Comment: Got the first two clues right away, which had me thinking about entropy, but I didn't figure out the last one. Gave up and checked this answer. Nice! xD